Download PDF files without opening it automatically
I am writing a Chrome Extension that bulk download files from specific sites. Understand there are Download Manager like DownloadThemAll that is super awesome in that area, but I need a lot of customization with my bulk download from those web sites. All is going well except that Chrome will automatically open the PDF files with Adobe, so if my bulk download has 50 PDF files, all of them will be open in Adobe when the bulk downloads finish. It is not happening to other file types like Word, Excel that are downloaded in the same batch.
I thought it was setting on my computer that causes all downloaded PDF to be open automatically, and have been Googling left & right without success. Then I realized it is probably not my computer because if I downloaded an PDF from my Yahoo email, the PDF file IS NOT open automatically, so it has to do with how the PDF were downloaded.
The code snippet that downloads the file is pasted below..
chrome.downloads.download({ conflictAction: "uniquify", url: `${URL_DownloadDocument}`, filename: `${row.doc["Export File Name"]}` }, (downloadId) => {
    if (downloadId == undefined) {
        logError(errorLogger, `Error downloading ${row.doc["Export File Name"]}`);
    } else {
        //add download id to downloadList
        //console.log(`Downloading ${row.doc["Export File Name"]} with download id ${downloadId} for row ${row.rowIdx}`);
        downloadIDList[downloadId] = row.rowIdx;
        currentDownloadCount++;
    }
});

Appreciate any help I can get. I have spent far too many hours trying to fix this issue.
Thanks!

Extensions can't change this behavior, AFAIK. There's an option in browser settings Open certain file types automatically after downloading which has a Clear button.

That is what I thought too, but my Chrome setting is already cleared. What I don't understand is why the PDF I downloaded from sites like Yahoo mail doesn't get open automatically. Clearly there is something that can be done on the browser from how the PDF were downloaded so they don't open automatically.

Try comparing the network requests using chrome://net-export.
